# read values into a list and print with brackets on one line comma delimited

Tags: python, list, loops, printing, brackets

Learning python and need to read numbers from a list, then use a statement to decipher if each integer in the list is positive. Then output to one single horizontal line with one set of brackets. see below:

```
Input: [10, 5, 3, 21, 2, -6]

Output: should look like - [10,5,3,21,2]
```

This is what I have gotten so far:

```
user_nums = [10, 5, 3, 21, 2, -6]

for num in user_nums:
    if num > 0:
     print([num], end=', ')
```

> output: [10][5][3][21][2]

How do I make this read a user input list?

Comment: also does it matter if the list is like this [10,5,3,21,2] or if its like this 10

Answer (score 0):

```
out = []
lst = [10, 5, 3, 21, 2, -6]
for num in lst:
    if num >= 0:
        out.append(num)
print(out)

# using list Comprehension
out_c = [x for x in lst if x >= 0]
print(out_c)
```

Comment: the is great and i will read up on the comprehensions, how do I get the spaces out of the output from [10, 5, 3, 21, 2, -6] **to** [10,5,3,21 2,-6]

Comment: That's python formatting of list